# closing the figure window when pressing the mouse button on the X

Tags: matlab, user-interface, mouseevent, mouse

I have a GUI that runs for a few minutes.
in this GUI I have images that are shown continuesly using the lines-

```
     axes('Position',[.3 .25 .3 .5]);
     image(imcell{1,2});
```

the problem is that even if I use my mouse to close the window by pressing the X in the left upper edge , there is a new window opened up showing those images until the end.

so how can I break the GUI from working (closing it) without getting a new window.

I guess its something like the "windowbuttonpressfcn" or "buttonpressfcn", but-

1. I dont think that pressing on the x is considered as a press becuase its outside the window..
2. I tried using the get(hobject,'currentpoint') but it didn't work and I think that's not the way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `axes` pops up a new window, so closing it will not help if you keep opening new figures in your code. You must check if the window/figure has been closed and skip plotting in that case, e.g.

```
% create the figure somewhere in the code
h=figure(1);  

% ... 

% your image processing loop
while(do_work)
    if ishandle(h)
       axes('Position',[.3 .25 .3 .5]);
       image(imcell{1,2});
    end
end
```

If you now close the figure window, `ishandle(h)` will return 0 and plots will not show.

When the figure is closed the `DeleteFcn` event is fired. If you want to do custom job on closing the figure you should connect an event handler to your figure handle:

```
set(h, 'DeleteFcn', @my_close_function)
```

In your close function you can do cleanup work, including stopping any process that is going on in your program.

Comment: o.k, but it solves only part of my problem- I did not mention it before but I have also audio files that will keep on playing, even if the window won't be shown. I need something that will realy close the entire procces not only what the eye can see on the screen.. have any other ideas?